# Count number of pairs across elements in a list in R?

Tags: r

Similar questions have been asked about counting pairs, however none seem to be specifically useful for what I'm trying to do.

What I want is to count the number of pairs across multiple list elements and turn it into a matrix. For example, if I have a list like so:

```
myList <- list(
  a = c(2,4,6),
  b = c(1,2,3,4),
  c = c(1,2,5,7),
  d = c(1,2,4,5,8)
)
```

We can see that the pair `1:2` appears 3 times (once each in `a`, `b`, and `c`). The pair `1:3` appears only once in `b`. The pair `1:4` appears 2 times (once each in `b` and `d`)... etc.

I would like to count the number of times a pair appears and then turn it into a symmetrical matrix. For example, my desired output would look something like the matrix I created manually (where each element of the matrix is the total count for that pair of values):

```
> myMatrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    0    3    1    2    2    0    1    1
[2,]    3    0    1    3    2    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    2    3    1    0    0    0    0    1
[5,]    2    2    0    0    0    0    1    1
[6,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[7,]    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0
[8,]    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: probably made a mistake .. `tcrossprod(sapply(myList, function(x) table(factor(x, 1:8))))`

Comment: `microbenchmark` shows that @user20650  `trcrossprod` is  300 times faster than @akrun 's   `Reduce` code is.

Comment: I think the answers supplied only work if you guarantee there are no duplicate entries in each source vector.   If there are, e.g.   `myList$a = c(2,4,2)`  then you can't distinguish between the  unwanted diagonals and the actual pair  `2,2` found .

Comment: Oh, and I think won't work if the input vectors are not ordered, either

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inspired by @akrun's answer, I think you can use a crossproduct to get this very quickly and simply:

```
out <- tcrossprod(table(stack(myList)))
diag(out) <- 0

#      values
#values 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#     1 0 3 1 2 2 0 1 1
#     2 3 0 1 3 2 1 1 1
#     3 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
#     4 2 3 1 0 1 1 0 1
#     5 2 2 0 1 0 0 1 1
#     6 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
#     7 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
#     8 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

---

**Original answer:**

Use `combn` to get the combinations, as well as reversing each combination.
Then convert to a `data.frame` and `table` the results.

```
tab <- lapply(myList, \(x) combn(x, m=2, FUN=\(cm) rbind(cm, rev(cm)), simplify=FALSE))
tab <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, unlist(tab, rec=FALSE)))
table(tab)

#   X2
#X1  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#  1 0 3 1 2 2 0 1 1
#  2 3 0 1 3 2 1 1 1
#  3 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
#  4 2 3 1 0 1 1 0 1
#  5 2 2 0 1 0 0 1 1
#  6 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
#  7 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
#  8 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: After revisiting the code, it seems that under certain conditions (which I haven't figured out yet), akrun's code was producing small errors where it wouldn't sum the total number of pairs correctly. That coupled with the speed increase made me change this to the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

We could loop over the `list`, get the pairwise combinations with `combn`, `stack` it to a two column dataset, convert the 'values' column to `factor` with `levels` specified as 1 to 8, get the frequency count (`table`), do a cross product (`crossprod`), convert the output back to logical, and then `Reduce` the `list` elements by adding elementwise and finally assign the `diag`onal elements to 0. (If needed set the `names` attributes of `dimnames` to NULL

```
out <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(myList, function(x) 
        crossprod(table(transform(stack(setNames(
          combn(x,
         2, simplify = FALSE), combn(x, 2, paste, collapse="_"))), 
          values = factor(values, levels = 1:8))[2:1]))> 0))
diag(out) <- 0
names(dimnames(out)) <- NULL
```

-output

```
> out
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 0 3 1 2 2 0 1 1
2 3 0 1 3 2 1 1 1
3 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
4 2 3 1 0 1 1 0 1
5 2 2 0 1 0 0 1 1
6 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
7 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
8 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: Master akrun, could you please check my answer. Am I completely wrong.  I tried to count all the combinations. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @TarJae Perhaps you may need to use `pivot_wider` at the end

Comment: Why not use the crossproduct to do all the hard work? - `\`diag<-\`(tcrossprod(table(stack(myList))), 0)` . I totally overlooked that possibility, but I think it works.

Comment: @thelatemail  next step:  do a time-test for `tcrossprod` vs your `lapply(combn)` code.  I'm betting on crossproduct :-)

Comment: see comment at question: that `tcrossprod` is 300 times faster than this.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It could be.  I haven't looked at the possibilities when I posted this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I thought of a solution based on @TarJae answer, is not a elegant one, but it was a fun challenge!

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Code

```
map_df(myList,function(x) as_tibble(t(combn(x,2)))) %>% 
  count(V1,V2) %>% 
  {. -> temp_df} %>% 
  bind_rows(
    temp_df %>% 
      rename(V2 = V1, V1 = V2) 
  ) %>% 
  full_join(
    expand_grid(V1 = 1:8,V2 = 1:8)
  ) %>% 
  replace_na(replace = list(n = 0)) %>% 
  arrange(V2,V1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = V1,values_from = n) %>% 
  as.matrix()
```

### Output

```
     V2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
[1,]  1 0 3 1 2 2 0 1 1
[2,]  2 3 0 1 3 2 1 1 1
[3,]  3 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
[4,]  4 2 3 1 0 1 1 0 1
[5,]  5 2 2 0 1 0 0 1 1
[6,]  6 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
[7,]  7 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
[8,]  8 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: Why bother with the rename?  Just swap the input order of subsequent calls maybe?

Answer (score 1):

First identify the possible combination of each vector from the list to a `tibble` then I bind them to one `tibble` and `count` the combinations.

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- as_tibble(t(combn(myList[[1]],2)))
b <- as_tibble(t(combn(myList[[2]],2)))
c <- as_tibble(t(combn(myList[[3]],2)))
d <- as_tibble(t(combn(myList[[4]],2)))

bind_rows(a,b,c,d) %>% 
    count(V1, V2)
```

```
      V1    V2     n
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1     1     2     3
 2     1     3     1
 3     1     4     2
 4     1     5     2
 5     1     7     1
 6     1     8     1
 7     2     3     1
 8     2     4     3
 9     2     5     2
10     2     6     1
11     2     7     1
12     2     8     1
13     3     4     1
14     4     5     1
15     4     6     1
16     4     8     1
17     5     7     1
18     5     8     1
```